# how using rainmeter script to launch windows app

Tags: rainmeter

Is anyone here know how to start an windows app like Netflix or Spotify ?
There is a trick to do that ?

there is not .exe file so at the moment the best I can do is open the netflix folder ...

here is my script :

```
[1Button2]
 Meter=Image
 X=36r
 W=24
 Y=r
 SolidColor=0,0,0,1
 ImageName=#apps#\NF.png
 LeftMouseUpAction= !execute ["C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_6.97.752.0_x64__mcm4njqhnhss8"][!RainmeterHideMeterGroup Hover][!RainmeterShowMeter Base][!RainmeterRedraw]
 Hidden=0
 AntiAlias=0
 Group=Apps
 ToolTipText="Netflix"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found is to create a shortcut and point the action to that shortcut. To do this on Windows 10 you drag the application you want from your system tray onto your desktop. This will create a .lnk file on your desktop that will open the application. In your case you would do that with the Netflix app, then use:

```
 LeftMouseUpAction = ["C:\Users\#YourUser#\Desktop\Netflix.lnk"][!RainmeterHideMeterGroup Hover][!RainmeterShowMeter Base][!RainmeterRedraw]
```

Just replace #YourUser# with the correct information.

You may also look into [Launching Windows Special Folders](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/launching-windows-special-folders/) on the Rainmeter docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. It's not optimal, but a bypass.

1. Right-click the Spotify Icon on your Start menu
2. Select "Pin to taskbar"

   [image: pin to taskbr]
3. From Taskbar [Shift + right-click] Spotify icon (make sure your Spotify app is closed while doing so, or else you won't get the needed option).
4. Select *Create shortcut*.

   [image: select shortcut]
5. Select *OK* from the warning pop-up.
6. A shortcut will be placed on your desktop. Store it anywhere you please.
7. Right-click the shortcut and select *Copy as path*.

   [image: copy path]
8. Place that path as the launch link in your meter skin.

   ```
   LocationPath6 = !Execute ["C:\Users\iftek\Desktop\Spotify - Shortcut.lnk"]
   ```